# How to create a link in a site that will login another site?

Tags: php, javascript, html, post, request

There is a simple site, let's call it http://foo.com/ , with a simple user/pass form that sends a post request to http://foo.com/login.php to login the user.

How to create a link in another site, say http://foo_autologin.com/ , that will login with a pre-determined password on http://foo.com/ and open it, logged in, in another tab?

Comment: Not a good idea to have autologin URLs. They can be even crawled by search engines. But it's doable. But you need to use _GET variables to authenticate as a link cannot pass _POST variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `http://foo_autologin.php` (doesn't have to be php, can be html) use Javascript to open a new window pointed to a file called proxy_login.php or something. Then use CURL to post the login credentials to `http://foo.com`. Checkout [Curl Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) and look in the examples.